# ¿Cómo enumerar distintas preguntas?

Tags: preguntas

Tengo una duda respecto a la enumeración de distintas preguntas. Considerando la siguiente oración...

> En nuestra página web oficial encontrarás la respuesta a preguntas como: ¿dónde nos encontramos?, o ¿cómo puedes hacer el pago?

¿Están correctamente los dos puntos? Y, ¿las preguntas deberían empezar por mayúscula?

En mi opinión, no deberían empezar por mayúsculas, pues es una enumeración, al estilo de...

> Voy a comprar: manzanas, tomates o pan

Pero las preguntas son oraciones enteras, así que me encuentro algo confuso.

Si es posible, me gustaría poder preguntar si pasa lo mismo en catalán.

¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En general, las preguntas no deben empezar con mayúsculas si el inicio de la pregunta no es el inicio del enunciado. El DPD [dice](https://www.rae.es/dpd/interrogaci%C3%B3n) (punto 2d):

> Los signos de apertura (¿ ¡) se han de colocar justo donde empieza la pregunta o la exclamación, aunque no se corresponda con el inicio del enunciado; en ese caso, la interrogación o la exclamación se inician con minúscula.

El punto 2f tiene un ejemplo muy parecido al de la pregunta:

> Me abordó en la calle y me preguntó: ¿Cómo te llamas?, ¿en qué trabajas?, ¿cuándo naciste?

Como se ve, las distintas preguntas en la enumeración empiezan con minúscula. Parece ser que la primera pregunta después de los dos puntos debe escribirse con mayúscula, lo cual es distinto a otros tipos de enumeraciones.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por responder de una manera tan clara y rápida. Solucionaste mis dudas, ¡gracias!